# SQL Query Error: date format picture ends before converting entire input into string

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, to-date

I'm getting an Error when I run the query below:

```
 to_date('30-APR-19 09.53.35.000000 AM', 'DD-Mon-yy hh24.mi.ss')
```

> Date format picture ends before converting entire input into string

Can I get an assistance please

Comment: Hello I'm using Oracle. Thanks for the help

Comment: still getting error

Comment: Worth a mention: Hour can be shown either with AM/PM or in 24 hour format. Your input has AM (and you mention it can also be PM). So, then, regardless of anything else, your format model shouldn't be hh**24**.mi. ... - it should be ... hh.mi.ss  AM (as Bob Jarvis has shown).

Answer (score 2):

The major problem you've got is that your date-and-time string can't be parsed using TO_DATE - you'll need to use TO_TIMESTAMP. The issue is that TO_DATE doesn't recognize the `FFn` format specifier, which is used to process fractional seconds. This makes sense because DATE values are only accurate to the second. So you'll need to use

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('30-APR-19 09.53.35.000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM')
```

Which will return a TIMESTAMP value. If you really need this to be a DATE rather than a TIMESTAMP you can cast the value to DATE by using

```
CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('30-APR-19 09.53.35.000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM') AS DATE)
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=81862219a0f7e453e31bef7e09d3aff5)

Comment: Hello Bob Jarvis, Thank you very much for the assistance.  TO_TIMESTAMP('30-APR-19 09.53.35.000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM')     this is working perfectly ... How can I add PM to this code as the query that I need to run will also include time with PM?

Comment: With this I'm getting an error  "missing right parenthesis". Also how can I add PM to the code aswell.                                                                                                 CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('30-APR-19 09.53.35.000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM') AS DATE

Comment: The `AM` format specifier will handle `PM` in the date string just fine. [See this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dfe22e211537625c11d7650eecf8921c)

Comment: With this I'm getting an error "missing right parenthesis".                         CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('30-APR-19 09.53.35.000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM') AS DATE

Comment: @amy You are missing the closing bracket after `as date`. It's `cast(xxx as yyy)`.

Comment: @William Robertson thanks a lot working perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `to_date` function and miliseconds can be ignored using # as following:

```
to_date('30-APR-19 09.53.35.000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.###### AM')
```

Number of # is equal to number of 0s after dot(.)

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e017838ed87fbea4c2b20cde485cd0a)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the help will try this :-)